# PHP remove duplicates in a large array

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I was removing duplicates from an array, i have used  `array_unique($array)`,

here an example for the array i tested on: `[7 6 4 3 3 4 9]`.

```
'the initial order of the values must be kept'
```

Here's my Function:

```
 function rmrepeat ($array) {
    $array2 = array_unique($array); 
    return $array2; 
 } 
 // Input Array 
 $a=array(7, 6, 4, 3, 3, 4, 9); 
 $newArray = rmrepeat($a);
```

### Then i got 2 main errors:

> - when i tested it on an array with 299 elements it didnt work.
> - second problem is that it didnt return the last element of the array

**What i have tried:**

- i tried to search on google on who to remove duplicates in large arrays but didnt find the result i'm looking for
- and i have tried the function end($array) then array_push function to add the last element to my function, but it didnt work too, and i guess it isnt even the right solution.
  and i didnt receive any clear error to share with you.

what can the problem be?

thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php ?

Comment: Use array_unique for remove same value.

Comment: i have used it (i mentioned it above), with all the $sort_flags too.

Comment: Can you show us your code please  ?

Comment: Also share what is the expected result.

Comment: @RomainV 

`function rmrepeat ($array) {

$array2 = array_unique($array);
return $array2;

} 

// Input Array 
$a=array(1, 2, 5, 2, 9); 
$newArray = rmrepeat($a);
'

Comment: tested for 450 values, working fine:- https://3v4l.org/rRN50

Comment: The code you've given works just fine [demo](https://3v4l.org/VGu88) - what expected outcome are you looking for exactly?

Comment: @jibsteroos He wants the second `2` to remain and remove the first.

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie that is weird, cz i was doing a codingame test, and i wrote it, it told me that i doesnt return the last value et it doesnt work on 299 elements, and i tested it on my computer and it is working well... so maybe the test is wrong, thank you.

Comment: @OmarElRafhi It will not keep the last item. If you input `[2,2]` then it's the first that is keept and the second that is deleted when using array_unique as it is. But if you reverse before array_unique, you will keep the last `2`

Comment: @Andreas i know, but in the test, they said: (the initial order of the values must be kept)

Comment: @OmarElRafhi If you reverse an array then reverse again, the order will be kept.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this
$a=array(7,6,4,3,3,4,9); 
$newArray = array_unique($a);
print_r($newArray);
```

or this one

```
$a=array(7,6,4,3,3,4,9);
$count = count($a);
$c = [];
for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++){
  if(!in_array($a[$i],$c)){
     array_push($c,$a[$i]);
  }
}
 print_r($c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. So I'm 100% sure that you wrongly thought that the last value is omitted. In fact it is removed because it's repeated and you asked all duplicate values to be removed by running `array_unique()`. For a simple test run this code and check if you see those problems again.

```php
function rmrepeat ($array) {
    $array2 = array_unique($array); 
    return $array2; 
} 

$a = [];
for($i=0;$i<1000;$i++){
    array_push($a, $i);
}

echo "Before removing duplicates: ", (string)count($a), PHP_EOL;

$a = rmrepeat($a);

echo "After removing duplicates: ", (string)count($a), PHP_EOL;
```

here there would not be any duplicated value so there will not be any change in the array length. if you change `array_push($a, $i);` with `array_push($a, rand(100, 200));` then many indices would be deleted and in most cases last item will be deleted too.

Answer (score -1):

In order to keep the last item when using array_unique you need to reverse the array first to make the last item first.

```
$arr = ["a" => 7, "B"=>6, "C"=>4, "D"=>3, "E"=>3, "F"=>4, "G"=>9];
var_dump($arr);

$arr = array_reverse($arr); // reverse to remove first occurence
$arr = array_reverse(array_unique($arr)); // array_unique and reverse back again

var_dump($arr);
```

Now it will keep "E" => 3 and remove "D", and "F" remains but "C" is removed.
https://3v4l.org/7P4IP

---

If order means keys then you can add `true` as second parameter to array_revers to keep the keys.

```
$arr = [1, 2, 5, 2, 9];
var_dump($arr);

$arr = array_reverse($arr, true);
$arr = array_reverse(array_unique($arr), true);

var_dump($arr);
```

returns

```
array(4) {
  [0] => int(1)
  // Notice key 1 is missing with value 2
  [2] => int(5)
  [3] => int(2)
  [4] => int(9)
}
```

https://3v4l.org/DkETK

Comment: that is a solution,but as i said above, i should keep the order the same, i'm not allowed to change the order of  values, 
this is a question in a codingame test

Comment: Didn't seems to be working for numeric index:- https://3v4l.org/dZqND  (BTW i am not a down-voter)

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie That is because with indexed array, array_reverse does not keep the key. In reality it works, it keeps the correct value but the keys are reset. See the example here: https://3v4l.org/0b1ko The `2` after `5` is kept but keys are reset

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie i guess my questions isnt clear enough, i will do the next test, and at that time i will get all the details and what code i wrote and what exact result i have got, to write a very clear question. thanks

Comment: @OmarElRafhi What do you mean with order? is it keys? It's very important that you use the correct wording or explain in details what you mean. Because order and keys are not the same.

Comment: @Andreas you are right, i didnt pay attention to that, actually it's the order of the values that i can't change. the keys i can.

Comment: @OmarElRafhi in that case my answer should work. (Either of them).

Answer (score -1):

Another solution that could help, which I don't recommend is to override the default memory capacity. You can do this using this:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1')
```

Further Reading:
http://php.net/memory_limit